# Use a variable inside a variable in substring in batch file

Tags: batch-file

i am trying to get a list of directories , sub directories and files at a given path ,which will be passed at runtime. i dont need the runtime path parameter in the list. 
My code is producing file with fully qualified path.
Following is the code that i am trying with :-

`@echo off
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set srcf=%~1
    for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (' dir /s /b %srcf% ') do (  call :proc "%%a" )
    :proc
    set var=%~1
    set "value=%var: !srcf!=%"
    echo !value! >> list.log`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of:

```
set "value=%var: !srcf!=%"
```

try:

```
set "value=!var: %srcf%=!"
```

`%var: !srcf!=%` would delay-expand `srcf`, keeping the old value of `var`